# Why is the 'this' keyword not a reference type in C++

Tags: c++, this, keyword

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Why ‘this’ is a pointer and not a reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645994/why-this-is-a-pointer-and-not-a-reference)
>   [SAFE Pointer to a pointer (well reference to a reference) in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320436/safe-pointer-to-a-pointer-well-reference-to-a-reference-in-c)

The `this` keyword in C++ gets a pointer to the object I currently am.

My question is why is the type of `this` a pointer type and not a reference type.
Are there any conditions under which the `this` keyword would be `NULL`?

My immediate thought would be in a static function, but Visual C++ at least is smart enough to spot this and report `static member functions do not have 'this' pointers`. Is this in the standard?

Comment: Dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/645994/why-this-is-a-pointer-and-not-a-reference

Comment: Not and exact duplicate!  The other question does not address the secondary questions posed here, like "can `this` ever be null?".  I was in the middle of answering that when this question was closed.

Comment: On the question of whether `this` can be null, the answer is no, not in a well formed program.

Comment: In practice, null `this` happens.  If you have a pointer to an object, and the pointer is null, and you try to call a method (e.g., `p->method()`), you'll often crash in the method because `this` is `NULL`.  I'm sure there are variations by compiler.  But `this` will never be null in a correct program.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

See Stroustrup's [*Why is `this` not a reference*](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#this)

> Because "this" was introduced into C++ (really into C with Classes) before references were added. Also, I chose "this" to follow Simula usage, rather than the (later) Smalltalk use of "self".

Comment: Why the downvote ? , this comes from BS  (apparently)

Comment: Maybe someone thought I copied the answer from the duplicate question (which is not the case, I've just discovered it in this second).

Answer (score 3):

Because references weren't added to C++ until later. By then it was too late to change it.

Answer (score 0):

(probably not a complete answer)
There is always the situation when an object needs to delete itself with the "dangerous"

```
delete this;
```

So it probably have to be a pointer.

M.

Comment: If it were a reference you could `delete &this;`.

Comment: `delete &this` might even have an advantage over `delete this` in that the additional `&` might make you ask yourself if you're actually allowed to delete the current object, ie. if it was dynamically allocated on the heap. `delete this` looks much more unobtrusive in this respect, IMO.